# Создание адаптивных речевых "тучек/облачков" для комиксов

Tags: delphi, pascal

Пишу программу по созданию комиксов с готовыми шаблонами в Delphi. Возник вопрос: как сделать тучки для персонажей, чтобы они могли общаться.

[image: Тучки]

У меня получаются однотипные и стандартные: не изменить размер, не направить тучку в другую сторону и если понадобится что-то дописать, то уже не влазит. Просмотрел кучу программ по созданию комиксов. Уж очень живые, подвижные и изменяемые они у создателей таких программ получаются. Как они это делают? Может кто-нибудь помочь мне в этом вопросе?

Comment: Видимо Ваши "тучки" - это просто bmp/jpeg. А их оптимально рисовать векторно (то есть, именно рисовать, динамически рассчитывая размеры).

Comment: Например, можно взять за основу http://www.delphigroups.info/2/c0/208134.html (код из последнего сообщения). Дорабатываем под остальные типы "тучек", соединяем с кодом по изменению размеров контролов в runtime (так же гуглится)... Profit :)